# Disturbuted job running on the number of servers each time by redisson

Tags: kotlin, synchronization, redisson

I have a scheduled job( jb1 ) on 10 servers. I want some number of servers to run it each time, for example only 3 servers.  I am interested in using redisson to handle it in kotlin. It’s important, if a jb1 server failed,  should one of the other servers run jb1.
Is it possible with redisson?
How should I implement it?